# NG-repeat Filter By two ranges

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show all events a month, something like this: 
Enero: event1, event2, event3
Febrero : Event5, event6.........

I am getting the information in a json in this format

```
events = [{ Name: event1, dateStart: 2014-02-01, dateEnd: 2014-02-07} ]....
```

How I can show only events with ng-repeat each ADDING ranges to specify the month.

Comment: You want to filter based on start date or end date?

Comment: I need filter based on startDate. Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. Tell me if it help

`ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'dateStart':true"`